# How to horizontally slide views on swipe gesture in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, gesture-recognition, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

In my iPhone app, I want that the user can slide views on swipe gesture.

I want that on swipe gesture the views should horizontally slide as if all the views are stitched together.

It should be a smooth motion of views.

What should I do?

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you should be adding a `UIScrollView` as your parent view, and adding these other views as subviews of the scroll view, setting their `x` offsets where they need to be to have them "stiched together". You get the horizontal scrolling for free, and things work as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks once again jer. I will try this out later and inform you. Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up a NavigationController to push and pop views to the stack. Then in your viewController you can add gestures.